# Task Scheduler windows to check the file is running or not

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a task in task shaduler on windows which executed a xx.bat program whenever the program isn't running. The question is, how can i check the program is running or not whenever my computer is ready/on. So i just want to check the bat isn't running. When the bat isn't running, the task shaduler will run the bat.

Comment: `tasklist` or `tasklist /v` combined with `find` or `findstr` should do.

Answer (score 2):

If it was an `exe` you want to check,  Stephan's comment would do it. But running bat files are just shown as cmd.exe in the task list as long as you don't give the process a name. So the point is to start your bat file with a certain "name". You can achieve this starting with this command:

```
start "somename" xx.bat
```

Now it can be found with `tasklist` and `findstr` easily:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET running=0
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('tasklist^ /v^| findstr /i /c:"somename"') DO SET running=1
IF NOT %running%==1 (
    start "somename" c:\SomePath\xx.bat
)
```